# Como utilizar uma variável no resources do Yaml

Tags: resources, yaml

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: UTIL_PIPELINE
    type: git
    name: UTIL_PIPELINE
    ref: refs/heads/master
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: DOMAIN
    source: DOMAIN-HMG
    **branch: $(stage)**
extends:
  template: azure-ci-c++-base.yml@UTIL_PIPELINE
  parameters:
    stepList:
    - download: DOMAIN
      displayName: 'Baixando os artefatos DOMAIN-**$(stage)**'
```

Dentro do Resources não está funcionando, mas dento do extends, funciona corretamente.
Alguém sabe como resolver?